# Explain to me how await user.save() works when schema name is User

Tags: mongodb, express

```
module.exports.updatePassword = async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;
  const { oldPassword, newPassword } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await User.findById(userId);

    const isPasswordValid = await user.isValidPassword(oldPassword);

    if (!isPasswordValid) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "Incorrect old password" });
    }

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const newHashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, salt);
    const oldHashedPassword = user.password;

    if (oldHashedPassword === newHashedPassword) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({
          message: "New password should not be the same as old password",
        });
    }

    user.password = newHashedPassword;
    await user.save();

    return res.json({ message: "Password updated successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Server error" });
  }
};
```

This is the userSchema with name User but in above code user.save() is used to update data - can anyone explain this?

exprots Users = mongoose.model('users', userSchem)

Comment: What exactly do you need explained? It saves the user. (If this is Mongoose it should be tagged with that as well.)

Comment: As we you ' await User.findById(userId) ' to stroe data of user related to id in variable user . for update the smae I usually  use find and update like  await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId) so how it will update just by calling save method on variable user

Comment: `findById` **finds** the user by ID *(it does nothing else)*. You *(optionally)* update a user property; if you did, you save the user. I don't understand the confusion--saving a user saves the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `User.findOne` returns a `Document`, which is stored in the variable `user`.

As an instance of a Document, that object will possess all of the methods defined on the prototype: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html

[save](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-save) is one such method, which you called with `user.save()`

From the documentation, the save method

> Saves this document by inserting a new document into the database if document.isNew is true, or sends an updateOne operation only with the modifications to the database, it does not replace the whole document in the latter case.